# Searching by color (RGB, LSV, etc). Has anybody implemented this?

Tags: color-space, algolia

I can't find any documentation about implementing search by color with algolia. I have about 5k images. I want the user to be able to select any RGB color and have results populate with colors closely related to the chosen color. Has anybody implemented anything like this with success?

Answer (score 1):

If you have RGB (or LSV) values for each of your picture, this can be implemented using [filters](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#filters).

Let's suppose you have a slider or a color picker that allows the user to pick a specific RGB value. The idea is now to give as a result all colors belonging to the sphere of center `<RGB chosen by user>` and radius `<pick a constant>`. To do so, you will have to build the filter request parameter using this value chosen by the user and this constant you picked while writing your application.

With a concrete example:

- The user picks the value `{R: 128, G: 15, B:200}`
- You chose the constant `10`
- You indexed records containing the fields `r`, `g` and `b`.

You will then build the following filter from those values
`"r:118 TO 138 AND g:5 TO 25 AND b:190 TO 210"`.
You can then happily make a search request using this filter as the `filters` parameter.

Note that I am using RGB here for the example. While RGB should be fine in most cases, you can always turn yourself to CIE LAB for example, which was *designed* to make color close *numerically* also close according to the *human eye perception*.

Comment: Thanks Léo for the very detailed example. Each image will have 5 corresponding RGB values going from most prominent to least prominent in the image. Would 5 different queries need to be executed to perform this search or is there a sort we could do on the filtered results? Or is there another way to achieve this? The matches of the most prominent images should obviously be shown before the matches of the least prominent colors

Comment: Unfortunately yes. However the reason is because of the way filters are handled by the engine. According to the documentation: it is not possible to have ` FILTER1 OR (FILTER2 AND FILTER3)` (for performance reason).
This rules out writing a filter retrieving objects that satisfies *any* RGB value. You will have to do 5 queries, remove duplicates between queries and append the result of the queries according to the ranking you want.

Comment: @LéoErcolanelli is right, the way is to use filters and LAB is better for these range queries. Here is a live example: https://www.typographicposters.com/posters?r=185&g=129&b=181